# Running a JS function automatically multiple times through jQuery

Tags: javascript

I am currently adding a feature to a genealogy website I am currently working on which is based on the Webtrees open source software.

So here is where I am at:
[image]

So originally, the software allows the user to press the individual node to expand/compress its content. And that works through the following code:

```
TreeViewHandler.prototype.expandBox = function(j, i) {
    if (jQuery(i.target).hasClass("tv_link")) {
        return !1
    }
    j = jQuery(j, this.treeview);
    var p = j.parent(),
        o = j.attr("abbr"),
        n = this,
        l, k;
    if (p.hasClass("detailsLoaded")) {
        k = p.find(".collapsedContent"), l = p.find(".tv_box:not(.collapsedContent)")
    } else {
        l = j;
        k = j.clone();
        p.append(k.addClass("collapsedContent").css("display", "none"));
        var m = this.loadingImage.find("img").clone().addClass("tv_box_loading").css("display", "block");
        j.prepend(m);
        n.updating = !0;
        n.setLoading();
        j.load(n.ajaxUrl + "getDetails&pid=" + o, function() {
            "function" === typeof CB_Init && CB_Init();
            j.css("width", n.zoom / 100 * n.boxExpandedWidth + "px");
            m.remove();
            p.addClass("detailsLoaded");
            n.setComplete();
            n.updating = !1
        })
    }
    j.hasClass("boxExpanded") ? (l.css("display", "none"), k.css("display", "block"), j.removeClass("boxExpanded")) : (l.css("display", "block"), k.css("display", "none"), l.addClass("boxExpanded"));
    this.getSize();
    return !1
};
```

What I'm trying to do is I'm trying to make the button I placed on the top left, which is to expand/compress ALL boxes in one click work. The one in showing/hiding females already work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var female = false
    $(".tv_hidefemales").click(function(){
        if (female == false) {
            $(".tvF").hide();
            female = true
        } else {
            $(".tvF").show();
            female = false
        }
    });
    $(".tv_expandCompress").click(function(){
        tvHandler.expandBox($(".tv"), 0);
    });
});
```

Comment: probably you may have added the same script file multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that I can just take advantage of a looping jQuery .click() function.